# Eclipse with texclipse code completion

Tags: code, auto-completion, texlipse

I am using **Eclipse** with **texclipse**. **Code completions** are not showing up for some  of the commands. For example: `\mbox{}`, `\mathcal{}` and for some others that i cannot recall at the moment.

*(If this single command does not suffice for answering why it doesn't show up in code completition let me know, then i will do thorough search of those commands.)*

**How is it possible to make specific commands availible in code completition?**